# SQL Sum of orders by date

Tags: sql

I should know this but for some reason its getting me stumped.

This simple code is outputting all orders by day

```
USE [K.1]
Select CreatedAt,Identifier,RoundedPriceSum from StarOrder
where SiteID = 1
and OrderType <>2
and CreatedAt between '2015/01/01' and '2015/08/20'
```

CreatedAt is a date, Identifier is unique order ID and RoundedPriceSum the total of the order.

Is it possible to amend the code to provide a total of RoundedPriceSum per day_

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag your question so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
Select cast(CreatedAt as date) as CreatedDay, SUM(RoundedPriceSum)
from StarOrder so
where SiteID = 1 and OrderType <> 2 and
      CreatedAt >= '2015-01-01' and
      CreatedAt < '2015/08/20'
group by cast(CreatedAt as date)
order by CreatedDay;
```

Notes on changes to the query:

- Changed the dates to ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format.
- Replaced the `BETWEEN` with `>=` and `<`.  This works better for dates with times.
- Use `cast(as date)` to remove the time component.
- Added an `ORDER BY` so the results are in order by day.

Answer (score 1):

```
select s.CreatedAt,s.Identifier,x.tot
from StarOrder s
join 
(select CreatedAt,sum(RoundedPriceSum) as tot
from StarOrder
where SiteID = 1
and OrderType <>2
and CreatedAt between '2015/01/01' and '2015/08/20'
group by createdat) x
on x.createdat = s.createdat
where SiteID = 1
and OrderType <>2
and s.CreatedAt between '2015/01/01' and '2015/08/20'
```